# How to support 64bit iOS and pass the AppStore?

Tags: ios, app-store, 64-bit, arm64, iphone-64bit

February 1, 2015, all applications must support 64bit.
However I have a confusing about build setting (Valid architectures).

To pass the AppStore. What is the right build settings?

Do I have to add armv7, arm64 in Valid Architetures

Or Do I have to add only armv7 in Valid Architectures.

I have to support OS 5.1.1.

But, If I added arm64 in Valid Architectures, I couldn't build or launch on 5.1.1 device.

I already read this guide. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH3-SW1

But, I'm not sure.

Someone said "add arm64", but other said "You don't need arm64"

What's the right settings to pass the AppStore on February 1, 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode, in the build settings tab of your project, look for the architectures section.

You have to leave the value "Standar Architectures". That includes support for 32 and 64 bits:

[image]

By the way, if you want to build and test your app in a 5.1.1 device, you will have to remove the 64 bits support.

It is not possible to install one build that includes arm64 architecture on devices running iOS 5.x other than using the App Store.

So to install development or ad-hoc builds on a device with iOS 5.x you need to make an extra build that does not include 64 bit architecture.

When submitting to the App Store, the build can contain all architectures, and Apple will modify the binary on their end so the problem won't occur in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Problem is 
 = NO
So, I couldn't on build 5.1.1 Device. Because 5.1.1. device isn't supported arm64

Solution.
 = YES